# smbclient directory listing gives NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED

Tags: redhat, samba, configuration

I have been looking around to no avail.  RHEL 6.4

I can run the following from a remote server, and successfully authenticates against LDAP:

```
smbclient -L //tric4t/share -U username
```

Once I run   `smbclient //tric4t/share -U username`, then

```
smb: \> ls
NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED listing \*
```

I have the following log errors:

```
[root@tric4t samba]# tail -4 log.smbd
  smbd version 3.6.9-167.el6_5 started.
  Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2011
[2014/03/04 09:24:10.470639,  0] lib/util_sock.c:628(open_socket_in)
  open_socket_in(): setsockopt: SO_REUSEPORT = true on port 445 failed with error = Protocol not available

root@tric4t samba]# tail -4 log.nmbd
[2014/03/04 09:24:16,  0] lib/util_sock.c:628(open_socket_in)
  open_socket_in(): setsockopt: SO_REUSEPORT = true on port 137 failed with error = Protocol not available
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: One thing I noticed is that a directory I have read access to has the permissions of drwxrwxrwt                     The ones that fail is drwxrwxr--

Comment: Have you solved it? I'm facing same plobrem.Please tell me how did you solve it if you've done it.

Comment: I have the same error message but samba actually runs fine. Did you add firewall rules? Check here: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SetUpSamba

Answer (score 1):

I solved such issue caused by selinux. NMB reported protocol not available on port 137. SMB reported the same on port 139. I switched Selinux off on /etc/selinux/config and Samba started working fine. BTW this selinux is a great tool for people´s patience examination ;-)

Comment: that's not really good solution on disabling `SELinux`, you should resolve any issues with `SELinux` without disabling it...

Answer (score 1):

Changing SELinux security context for shared directory helped me

```
chcon -t samba_share_t /path/to/share
```

Comment: Not allowed to comment or vote but Max P's answer is the correct fix. However, you will probably want to add the recursive switch if you have existing files/folders: `sudo chcon -R -t samba_share_t /path/to/share`